# Excel VBA: create a word document with an excel file embedded in it

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am currently using a basic macro to create a formatted word document using form information entered into an excel sheet.

However, I would also like to create a new excel sheet using the same macro, and embed that sheet into the word document (not as a table, but as a file).

If someone can explain the general approach that ought to be taken, I can probably figure it out.  Thanks kindly.

Comment: If you're not embedding the worksheet as a table within the Word document, what are you looking for? Perhaps a clickable Excel icon that pops up the worksheet?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Word macro recorder you could insert Excel file into Word document something like this way:

```
Selection.InlineShapes.AddOLEObject ClassType:="Excel.Sheet.12", _ 
    FileName:="C:\Users\Your Name\Documents\Albums.xlsx", _
    LinkToFile:=True, DisplayAsIcon:=True, _
    IconFileName:="C:\Windows\Installer\{90140000-003D-0000-0000-0000000FF1CE}\xlicons.exe", _
    IconIndex:=1, IconLabel:="Albums.xlsx"
```